# How to check whether user is verified using instagram api?

Tags: json, api, httprequest, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to determine whether the user is verified but can't seem to access this info. I can't see anywhere in the Instagram Basic Display API for retrieving that field. So now I've also tried doing a GET call on `https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?a=1` but that doesn't work because it redirects to a log in page. How can I do this?!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via the API at this time.

Comment: Okay so is there another way I can do it? How about if I somehow pass my access token with the `https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?a=1` request?